# Is it possible to pass parameter to a global middleware in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

In laravel docs, I saw I can pass parameter to a route middleware but I have a global middleware that runs on every http request. I need to pass a variable to this global middleware. Is it possible to do? Or I have to use route middleware and explicitly define the middleware on every route?

Here is my simple test code

```
Route::get('{lang}/product', function($lang){
  return view('langtest');
});
```

I want to pass `$lang` to my global middleware.

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

   /*set the app locale*/
   \Log::info($request);     

    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: you can using $request->lang

Comment: No, the $request is empty.

Comment: okay.then i think its not an global middleware so that request is not passing through that middleware

Comment: Request is getting passed as I tested on every request I logged some info to see if the thread was inside that middleware. May be it is not possible with global middleware :(

Comment: can you show log

Comment: http://prntscr.com/grtqyk

Comment: as per your iamge its pretty sure $request is empty array.as  said earlier its not passing from that middleware

Comment: can you show how you declared global middleware

Comment: http://prntscr.com/grtri2

Comment: that looks good

Comment: Thank you for your help so far. :) Let me know if you have something in mind. I have been trying for info for global middleware but all search results says to use route middleware. 
I am going to use route middleware. 

Thanks again :)

Comment: @sadik.even i m trying here.for me also returned empty.let me check once

Comment: `$lang = $request->route('lang');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
Route::get('{lang}/product', function(){
  return view('langtest');
})->middleware('lang.lang-1');
```

in your middleware

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next,$lang)
{
    dd($lang);  
    return $next($request);
}
```

don't forget to define your middle ware into your kernel

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [

        'lang' => \App\Http\Middleware\YourMiddlewareName::class,
    ];
```